# Python .join() with a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Say I have this array:

```
foo = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
```

If I want to print the elements of the inner arrays, I would do something like this:

```
for array_ in foo:
    for element in array_:
        print element
```

After doing this, I would get this result:

```
a
b
c
d
```

How can I print each inner array vertically, then join it with the other array, like this?

```
ac
bd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> foo = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
>>> [''.join(a) for a in zip(*foo)]
['ac', 'bd']
```

`zip(*foo)` returns list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the input lists. And `join()` concatenates the content of the lists.

If the lists in the list of lists variable `foo` are large, you could use an efficient version of `zip()` from the `itertools` module:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> foo = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
>>> [''.join(a) for (a) in izip(*foo)]
['ac', 'bd']
```

Comment: I would recommend using `itertools.izip`, as `zip` creates a brand new list (O(n)) in memory

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version using `map()`:

```
import operator as op
map(op.add ,*foo)
=> ['ac', 'bd']
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` will work also:

```
["".join(x) for x in map(None,*foo)]
```

Just join again to get just the strings:

```
"\n".join(["".join(x) for x in map(None,*foo)])
```

In this case map behaves like zip, it transposes the elements:

```
In [39]: foo = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

In [40]: map(None,*foo)
Out[40]: [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [1]: foo = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

In [2]: print "\n".join("".join(f) for f in zip(*foo))
ac
bd
```

The inner call to `zip` will transpose the array:

```
In [3]: zip(*foo)
Out[3]: [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

The first `join` will concatenate each tuple together:

```
In [4]: ["".join(element) for element in zip(*foo)]
Out[4]: ['ac', 'bd']
```

Finally each element in the list is joined by the outer call to `join`